# Azure Data Factory failed while copying big data files

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-data-factory

I am using **Azure Data Factory** from copying data from **REST API** to **Azure Data Lake Store**. Following is the JSON of my activity

```
{
    "name": "CopyDataFromGraphAPI",
    "type": "Copy",
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "HttpSource",
            "httpRequestTimeout": "00:30:40"
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink"
        },
        "enableStaging": false,
        "cloudDataMovementUnits": 0,
        "translator": {
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "columnMappings": "id: id, name: name, email: email, administrator: administrator"
        }
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "MembersHttpFile",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "MembersDataLakeSink",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ]
}
```

The REST API is created by me. First for testing purpose I am returning just 2500 rows and my Pipeline was working fine. It copied the data from REST API call to Azure Data Lake Store.

After testing I update the REST API and now It is returning 125000 rows. I tested that API in REST client and its working fine. But in **Azure Data Factory's Copy Activity** It is giving following error while copying data to Azure Data Lake Store.

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToReadHttpFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read data from http source file.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.,Source=System,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "CopyDataFromGraphAPI"
}
```

The sink side is Azure Data Lake Store. Is there any limit of content size which I am copying from REST call to Azure Data Lake Store.

I also retested the pipeline by updating REST API call(2500 rows)  and It worked fine and when I updated API Call and It returns 125000 rows. My pipeline starts giving the same above mentioned error.

My source DataSet in Copy Activity is

```
{
    "name": "MembersHttpFile",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "WM_GBS_LinikedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "HttpFile",
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "email",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "administrator",
                "type": "Boolean"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "arrayOfObjects",
                "jsonPathDefinition": {
                    "id": "$.['id']",
                    "name": "$.['name']",
                    "email": "$.['email']",
                    "administrator": "$.['administrator']"
                }
            },
            "relativeUrl": "api/workplace/members",
            "requestMethod": "Get"
        }
    }
}
```

**Sink Data Set is**

```
{
    "name": "MembersDataLakeSink",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "DataLakeLinkService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreFile",
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "email",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "administrator",
                "type": "Boolean"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "arrayOfObjects",
                "jsonPathDefinition": {
                    "id": "$.['id']",
                    "name": "$.['name']",
                    "email": "$.['email']",
                    "administrator": "$.['administrator']"
                }
            },
            "fileName": "WorkplaceMembers.json",
            "folderPath": "rawSources"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no limit to file size. I've had a 10 gb csv with millions of rows and the data lake doesn't care.

What I can see is that while the error says "sink" side, the error code is UserErrorFailedToReadHttpFile so I think the issue may be solved if you change the httpRequestTimeout on your source, as of now it is "00:30:40" and maybe the row transferring is being interrupted because of it. 30 minutes is a lot of time for 2500 rows, but maybe 125k doesn't fit there.

Hope this helped!

Comment: But the response is coming in 10 minutes. And pipeline is failing around 11 minutes

Comment: Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. This points to an error on your REST API, not a data factory configuration issue. If you want, share with us your linked service and dataset so we can check if everything is right. Also try stressing your api with another tool, some values in between (10k rows, 40k rows, 80k rows), or maybe you are losing conectivity intermittently (if you are hosting the rest api).

Comment: I tested my API using Postman with 125K rows many times and Its working fine. I'll share with you runtime